# This is the question about integration ! I want to know how to approach this question.

Tags: integration

> Evaluate the integral
>   $$
> \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\frac{7+10\cot x}{10-7\cot x}\, dx
> $$

[This link is my approach. (Its size is over 2 MB, so I could not upload it at here. sorry)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/43d3kcrhxvt3mjk/2014-09-28%2014.54.16.jpg?dl=0)

I basically do not know how to approach this question. Please let me know how to approach this question. I don't really need answer if you give me the way to approach, but if you attach full explanation, I will appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Let $7=X\cos\alpha,10=X\sin\alpha$, where you can easily calculate $X$.
Then you want to integrate $$\frac{\cos\alpha\sin x+\sin\alpha\cos x}{\sin\alpha\sin x-\cos\alpha\cos x}$$
(Simplify it first).

Answer (score 0):

The approach to this is the substitution $u=\cot x$, so that $x=\operatorname{arccot} x$ and $dx=-\dfrac{1}{1+u^2}\,du$ so the integral becomes
$$
\int_{1}^{0}-\frac{7+10u}{10-7u}\frac{1}{1+u^2}\,du
$$
which should be easier, via partial fractions.